# Show that the sequence $a_n = -n+2$ is equal to $a_n = a_{n-1} + 2a_{n-2} + 2n - 9$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

My Working:

\begin{align}
a_0=&-0+2=2\\
a_1=&-1+2=1\\
a_2=&-2+2=0.
\end{align}
and $$a_2=a_{2-1}+2a_{2-2}+2(2)-9=-4.$$

I don't know what's wrong with my solution. I used this method on various questions but now I'm just ending up with the wrong answer.

Comment: As you are not really a newcomer, try to use MathJax in a correct way, for example instead of "a sub n" use : a followed by underscore followed by n.

Answer (score 3):

We have:

$$a_n=-n+2$$
$$a_{n-1}=-(n-1)+2=-n+3$$
$$a_{n-2}=-(n-2)+2=-n+4$$

And then

$$a_n-a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2}=-n+2-(-n+3)-2(-n+4)= 2n-9$$

Comment: This may seem like a really stupid question but why is : a_{n-1} = -(n-1) + 2 ? Edit : I tried using mathjax but for some reason it's not showing up right on my laptop :(

Comment: Imagine you have $f(x)=-x+2$ then $f(n)=-n+2$ also could be rewritten as $a_{n} = -n+2$ you could also have $a_{\text{jame_smith}}=-(\text{jame_smith})+2$  do you see where this is going?

Comment: @dydxx you can use a <sub> n </sub> as a function, like f(x). So when you pass f(x-1) you get, -(x-1) + 2. Did i get it right?

Comment: @jame_smith Well that is how I imagine it. Yes you would be correct.

Comment: @Jamie: you are correct!

Answer (score 1):

Solving it further we have -

$a_{2} = a_{2-1} + 2a_{2-2} + 2(2) - 9$

$a_{2} = a_{1} + 2a_{0} + 2(2) - 9$

$a_{2}$ = 1 + 2(2) + 2(2) - 9$

$a_{2}$ = 1 + 4 + 4 - 9$

= 0

Your mistake is you are using the value of $a_{0}$ = 0 but it is 2.

Comment: But in the body you can see where the user has problem he is asking about.

Comment: @jame_smith please clarify your question whether you want method to prove equations or mistake in your solution.